# Exact time in server python

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

I've a script that read a db and send sms to user in a specific time, my server is in london and my country Guatemala is (-6 Hours), i use:

```
local_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=-6)
```

I'm afraid of Daylight could change and my sms is send incorrectly

Is there any way to control this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library such as `pytz` to check the local time instead

```
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> tz= timezone('America/Guatemala')
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> tz.fromutc( datetime.utcnow() )
datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 22, 12, 4, 37, 2229, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Guatemala' CST-1 day, 18:00:00 STD>)
```

The accuracy of the library is as good as the accuracy of the underlying timezone database, so if it doesn't suit your purposes, please consider contributing to it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the current time in a given timezone:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('America/Guatemala'))
```

Example:

```
>>> print(now.strftime('%F %T %Z%z'))
2014-04-23 01:04:46 CST-0600
```

On *nix with tz database you could change your local timezone (stdlib-only solution):

```
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime, timezone

os.environ['TZ'] = ':America/Guatemala'
time.tzset()

# to get local time
print(datetime.now(timezone.utc).astimezone().strftime('%F %T %Z%z'))
# -> 2014-04-23 01:12:38 CST-0600
```